# Can nhibernate check for unique constraints, without it being the primary key

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a simple class, that has a `Name` member, used to uniquely identify an instance. This class is referenced in a ManyToMany-mapping which will use the `Name`(since it is the primary key) to create the mapping-table. The type of strings involved makes this very slow (length > 128 chars, often only differing in the last few). To speed it up I'd like to create an `auto_increment` column (I'm using MySQL) for the join, while still being able to have nhibernate sort out the uniqueness of my objects using the `Name`-column.

Here is an example of what it looks like. In reality the objects are a lot larger.

```
class MyObject{
  public String Name;
  public String Value;
}
//Mapping
Id(x => x.Name)
  .Length(255)
  .Unique();
Map(x => x.Value);
```

This works as intended. If I add a new `MyObject` to the table nhibernate will do a select first to see if a record with the same `Name` is already in the table.

I have an `ObjectHolder` that has a Set of `MyObject`

```
class ObjectHolder{
  public UInt64 Id;
  public ICollection<MyObject> MyObjects;
}
//Mapping
Id(x => x.Id)
  .GeneratedBy.Native();
HasManyToMany(x => x.MyObjects)
  .AsSet()
  .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

This will create a mapping using `ObjectHolder.Id` and `MyObject.Name`, which is slow. I want the `MyObject` to have an Id-column that is autogenerated and only used for the mapping-table, but not for the select-to-see-if-it-exists-checking that nhibernate does with the primary key.

I have altered the mapping to

```
class MyObject{
  public UInt64 Id;
  public String Name;
  public String Value;
}
//Mapping
Id(x => x.Id)
  .GeneratedBy.Native();
Map(x => x.Name)
  .Length(255)
  .Unique();
Map(x => x.Value);
```

This will create an auto_increment column and use it for the mapping-table, however it will now no longer check correctly if a record with the same `Name` already exists, which leads to duplicate entry exceptions.

Can I tell nhibernate to check the `Name` column instead the id, or annotate the `Id`-column so it is only used as a foreign key, but nothing else? Do I have to modify the manyToMany mapping?

Edit: It seems even worse if I have to use composite ids. All id properties are saved twice, once in the object itself and once in the mapping, which adds a huge time and storage space overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at this problem the wrong way, NH isn't supposed to be checking to see if it already exists for you. You should know if it already exists or not.

Checking if a name is unique should be part of your validation and business logic. As such you should check to see if the name is taken before trying to save.

If you were accessing the database yourself you could have handled the constraint violation. However, NHibernate does not support this as it would complicate batching. I.e. the batch would be saved when the transaction is flushed, and that would be the point the error is raised rather than where you persisted the entity. So the only sensible thing NH can do is rollback the whole transaction and throw an error.

Essentially the database constraint is just final failsafe to prevent invalid data, rather than something you rely on to check your business rules.

Comment: I think(hope) you misunderstood. The name is the unique ID for theis object. That the name already exists is by design, objects with the same name represent the same object. In this case I would expect nhibernate to update the object and then save/update the parent that holds the manyToMany-relation. I'm using an ORM exactly because I do not want to handle all manyToMany collections with the usual select, if exists update, else insert; recursively cycling through my entire hierarchy.

Comment: I just want nhibernate to use a different column (which for mysql has to be the primary key due to auto_increment) to do the database joins, nothing else.

Comment: Right, but if you tell NH that's the id column, then as far as NH cares that is the id, not name. You could set name to be the natural key but that doesn't change that much. The main thing is NH shouldn't really be checking if something already exists for you, by numeric id or by name. Since you're using an auto_increment column you would see the error immediately, but if you were using say hilo, NH wouldn't try and save the object to the DB until you committed the transaction, at which point it would save all the changes in a single batch (when supported by the DBMS).